# How to make this shaped button?

Tags: html, css, button

Button

[image]

How can I make this shaped button? I can use right side with "border-radius", but I have no clue how to implement left side.

Comment: what is the shaped of the button? sorry I can't access your link

Comment: Is the button background colored or have a background image?

Comment: @JosephMarikle Button itself has gradient but the background of the screen is an image.

Comment: @threeFatCat Right side is rounded outside and left side is rounded inside

Comment: @KevinCho So no masking either way. That makes it more difficult. :P

Comment: Hey, is it not the first example here you're looking for? https://codepen.io/mallendeo/pen/eLIiG

Comment: Please edit your question to include exactly what your requirements are, and what you've tried previously to do this yourself. This sure sounds like you want the volunteers on Stack Overflow to do your work for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CSS pseudo-selector ::before to accomplish this.

Select the element like so, and add the following styles:

```
.button::before {
    content: "";
    width: //whatever you choose to fit
    height: //whatever you choose to fit
    background-color: #fff !important;
    //this will hide the border of the element itself
    border-radius: //same radius as the element
    z-index: 9999; //hides the button border
    border-right: //same width as the element, solid black
    border-left: 0px; //so it doesnt show
    border-bottom: 0px;
    border-top: 0px;
}
```

Lastly is the positioning, I'm trusting that you will figure out how to position it correctly. Let me know if this works. It's basically a circle with only the right border showing, sitting over the button element.

Comment: I have done this, but I have background with an image where I cannot hide the part of the button with white.

Comment: @KevinCho ... then you _really_ have to show your actual markup and styles that you are already working with. Ask again (a new question) but explain the situation more and show enough for people to work with.

Answer (score 0):

A pure CSS solution consists of adding a circular "gradient" background image on top of the normal background image: HTML

```css
    .round {
        background:
            radial-gradient(circle at 0 50%, rgba(204,0,0,0) 30px, #c00 15px);
            border-top-right-radius:3em;
            border-bottom-right-radius:3em;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="round">By using radial gradients, you can simulate rounded corners with a negative radius. Just in this case, don't put the color stops at the exact same position, since the result will be too aliased in most browsers (and kinda still is in Webkit).</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EjE7c/2757/)